# Subversion checkout restriction

Tags: svn

I am working on the subversion & tortoise client, every thing is working fine with users restriction except the checkout, when a user checkout or use repo browser he will get all the folders viewable &  copy while he is not able to write on some of the directories as per the restriction, but what i want he can be able to checkout or Repo-Browser only the folder he/she has access.

Comment: Not possible. Make a few different repositories.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - Actually, it's very possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your client. It has to do with the server. Subversion has several standard methods of the server running. It can use its own simple server called `svnserve` or use Apache via several modules, or it can use a combination of `svnserve` and `sshd`.

The question is how is your server being executed. It is possible to setup your repository to restrict what parts of a repository a user can or cannot checkout, but it depends upon your system.

Check out the [Subversion online manual on server management](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html) -- especially the section on [access controls](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth.general). It'll give you an idea how you can restrict access to your repository.

Comment: "It is possible to setup your repository to restrict what repositories a user can or cannot checkout" Excuse me?

Comment: repositories -> parts of a repository

Answer (score 0):

For example, setting in authz file:

```
[/]
* = r

[/repoa]
* = r

[/repoa/trunk]
* = r

[/repoa/trunk/foldera]
usera = rw
userb = rw
userc = rw

[/repoa/trunk/folderab]
usera = rw
userb = rw

[/repoa/trunk/folderc]
usera = rw
userb = rw
* =
```

foldera: usera, userb, userc can read and write.
folderb: usera, userb can read and write. userc can read.
folderc: usera, userb can read and write. userc can see this folder(because of the /repoa/trunk setting with "r"), but can not read its sub-folder and files in it.